# how to copy from last position when connection error ucures PostgreSQL DB 100GB from remote server?

Tags: database

how to copy from last position when connection error ucures PostgreSQL DB 100GB from remote server ?
I had PosgreSQL DB on remote server it is ~100GB

I'm using PostgreSQL shell to copy from remote Db to file in my pc:

`\copy BINARY table TO 'C:\\TEMP\\file.txt';`

after coping 10-30GB usually connection is lost/drops and I get error something like:

> error server lost connections terminate abnormal

So how I can copy from last point/position then error occurred? Lets say: if I have copied 20GB and connection was lost I want to start from 20gb last point there error was and continue but NOT from 0 bytes from beginning?

I **CAN NOT** use pg_dump BUT I can use php and PostgreSQL shell!
I have NO SUPERUSER rights!

If I use pgAdmin query tool:

```
copy BINARY table TO 'C:\\TEMP\\file.txt';
```

I get error:

```
mydb=> copy BINARY table TO 'C:\\TEMP\\file.txt';
```

> ERROR:  must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
>   HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command
>   also works for anyone.

So im using

```
\copy BINARY table TO 'C:\\TEMP\\file.txt';
```

command in PostgresSQL shell

OR I can USE tools/software to get DB queries from remote Postgresql and from last position/last read query!
Please HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With those restrictions, you'll have to resort to doing what's possible with a `SELECT` command.

One approach would be to write a script which selects records from remote in primary key order. It should select a block of records (e.g. 1000) and insert them in the local host.

After each block is selected from remote and inserted on local, the loop should restart, with the starting point being the last inserted key + 1.

Since the source table doesn't have a primary key, you can as a last resort use the internal `cid`. But in this case it's very important that no changes must be done to the source table while its data is being copied, or there will be missed or duplicate records in the copy.

For example, using a test database prepared like this to represent the source database:

```
$ psql -tAc "CREATE ROLE so21202282 LOGIN PASSWORD 'so21202282'"

$ createdb so21202282 -O so21202282

$ psql -tAc "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE so21202282 to so21202282"

$ psql so21202282
# create table big_table (name varchar not null);
# alter table big_table owner to so21202282;
# insert into big_table SELECT md5(random()::text) AS name FROM (SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,10000) AS id) AS x;
# select count(*) from big_table;
 count
-------
 10000
(1 row)
# select * from big_table limit 10;
               name
----------------------------------
 121d50c1152512074770be4803147561
 8f1dbf52867fd95d585d5a6a02116957
 0f227635bcde2abc4e9d77b6911f43f2
 7b4490a325a978f10c8c1651bc44fc84
 79c1a77a0cb29f5a540653945f0cd1a0
 03595e4afc31f987874a7824ba58f8ee
 588ad3e66f70e109ccb780215d1e8e00
 ac63376de3e4dcf067283bd7de475d6d
 9b648ad199095b2cc9f575afe378e11e
 9e70c3c4a24ece1ac0e8c54be41ffd0a
(10 rows)
# \q
```

And another database like this to represent the target database:

```
$ createdb so21202282_target -O so21202282

$ psql so21202282_target -tAc 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "dblink"'

$ psql -tAc "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE so21202282_target to so21202282"

$ psql so21202282_target
# create table big_table_target (source_ctid tid primary key, name varchar not null);
# alter table big_table_target owner to so21202282;
# \q
```

This sample code will migrate data from the source database to the target database:

```
create or replace function get_last_local_ctid() returns tid as $$
  select case
    when COUNT(*) > 0 then (select max(source_ctid) from big_table_target)
    when COUNT(*) = 0 then '(0,0)'::tid
    end as max_ctid
  from big_table_target
$$ language sql;

create or replace function insert_from_next_remote_batch(start_ctid tid) returns integer as $$
declare
  inserted_rows integer default 0;
begin
  raise notice 'Copying data starting from cid %', start_ctid;
  insert into big_table_target
    select *
    from dblink(
      'dbname=so21202282 host=localhost user=so21202282 password=so21202282',
      'select ctid, name from big_table ' ||
      'where ctid > ''' || start_ctid || '''' ||
      ' order by ctid limit 1000' -- Change limit according to performance.
    )
    as source(ctid tid, name varchar);
  GET DIAGNOSTICS inserted_rows = ROW_COUNT;
  raise notice '% records copied', inserted_rows;
  return inserted_rows;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create or replace function migrate_data() returns void as $$
declare
  last_cid tid default (0,0);
  inserted_rows integer default 0;
  done boolean default false;
begin
  raise notice 'Starting data migration';
  while not done loop
    last_cid = (select * from get_last_local_ctid());
    raise notice 'Last local cid is %', last_cid;

    -- Use a new session via dblink to create an independent transaction.
    inserted_rows = (
      select *
      from dblink(
        'dbname=so21202282_target host=localhost user=so21202282 password=so21202282',
        'select insert_from_next_remote_batch(''' || last_cid || ''')'
      )
      as f(inserted_rows integer)
    );

    raise notice '% rows copied', inserted_rows;
    done = (inserted_rows = 0);
  end loop;
  raise notice 'Data migration complete';
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

This will be the output of running `select migrate_data();`:

```
NOTICE:  Starting data migration
NOTICE:  Last local cid is (0,0)
NOTICE:  1000 rows copied
NOTICE:  Last local cid is (8,40)
NOTICE:  1000 rows copied
NOTICE:  Last local cid is (16,80)
NOTICE:  1000 rows copied
NOTICE:  Last local cid is (24,120)
NOTICE:  1000 rows copied
NOTICE:  Last local cid is (33,40)
NOTICE:  1000 rows copied
NOTICE:  Last local cid is (41,80)
NOTICE:  1000 rows copied
NOTICE:  Last local cid is (49,120)
NOTICE:  1000 rows copied
NOTICE:  Last local cid is (58,40)
NOTICE:  1000 rows copied
NOTICE:  Last local cid is (66,80)
NOTICE:  1000 rows copied
NOTICE:  Last local cid is (74,120)
NOTICE:  1000 rows copied
NOTICE:  Last local cid is (83,40)
NOTICE:  0 rows copied
NOTICE:  Data migration complete
```

Comment: Thank You for Answer BUT I Dont have right to create DB on remote server or create file...or...JUST READ DB!P.S. I CAN NOT use pg_dump BUT I can use php and PostgresSQL shell! I have NO SUPERUSER rights!

Comment: I can use any SQL command line or pgAdmin scripts if I will have ORDERED DB structure: Now I had fields NO_ID:2,192,3,734,345,5,9,23..I can use SQL comand ORDER BY because it takes too long to sort 100-150GB....if I will have ORDERED DB I can track last saved to diks NO_ID number and start from last position.BUT now I have unordered structure of DB ? ANY SUGESTIONS ?

Comment: SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  MY_TABLE WHERE NO_ID > 1 AND NO_ID < 1000 ORDER BY NO_ID;

WITH this command teoreticaly I will get ALL COLUMS from 1 to 1000 and I can save them to disk the use 
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  MY_TABLE WHERE NO_ID > 1000 AND NO_ID < 2000 ORDER BY NO_ID;
SAve next 1000 record to diks BUT
SLQ command ORDER BY takes 2 days to sort 150Gb ON REMOTE SERVER...Any IDEAS ?

Comment: If you have such a big table with no primary key and no ordering, and no admin access, there are serious issues with that data. You may still be able to retrieve the records in order, though, if there is an internal [OID](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-oid.html) column on that table. Are you even allowed to access this data? Maybe you should talk to who owns it.

Comment: Of course if I have password and user name in this database its evrything allowed,but other thing I already emailled couple times support.NO support answer for 1 mounth...so I try to do it myself!Where is no solution ? If I have COLUMN ID_NO: with values 2,454,65,34,999,12344,3...to track last saved and if connection will be lost to start from last saved ?I mead write to fileNO_ID:2,454,65 and here connection lost,so findID_No:65 and continue...?

Comment: Yes, you would read 1000 records, insert them, and repeat. If the operation fails, you restart from the last inserted record + 1. This way you don't have to restart from the beginning.

Comment: How to Do that ? How to track fields in Postgressql ? And how to move to last field+1 ?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example that you can play with and adapt to your data structure. Please see the PostgreSQL manual to understand the commands used.